# Laravel random str number only

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible to I have $random = `str_random(10);` only get numbers and not letters?

> The purpose is to make invoice numbers. (if you have better
>   suggestions please let me know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php):

```
$random = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP native function `rand()`

```
rand(min,max);
```

or either `mt_rand(min,max)` to make bigger integers